# Material-UI X: Could not find the data grid context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm using `Data Grid Pro` component from Material-UI in my React app.

I tried to create a custom toolbar for the `DataGridPro` component using `GridToolbarColumnsButton`, `GridToolbarFilterButton`, `GridToolbarDensitySelector`, and `GridToolbarExport` components from the same package with the `DataGridPro` component.

I also could use a single `GridToolbar` component to replace all of the four components above.

I need to create the custom toolbar component in a separate component file.

I forked the code for custom toolbar example from Material UI here https://codesandbox.io/s/wduvx
and edited the code (separate the custom toolbar into a different component file) here https://codesandbox.io/s/data-grid-pro-toolbar-example-j004m

Both of the codes work fine but when I created another example from scratch here  https://codesandbox.io/s/data-grid-pro-toolbar-mine-up6ik, the code produced an error. It said that `Material-UI X: Could not find the data grid context` (as you can see in the codesandbox).

Here are the dependencies (in package.json file):

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.0",
"@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^4.0.0",
```

What's the problem and what's the solution for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You import from the wrong module, because you're using `DataGridPro` from `@mui/x-data-grid-pro`:

```
import { DataGridPro } from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro";
```

But you import the grid components in `@mui/x-data-grid`:

```
import {
  GridToolbarColumnsButton,
  GridToolbarFilterButton,
  GridToolbarDensitySelector,
  GridToolbarExport
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
```

Which should have been:

```
import {
  GridToolbarColumnsButton,
  GridToolbarFilterButton,
  GridToolbarDensitySelector,
  GridToolbarExport
} from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro";
```